# Setting credentials to uploaded files

Tags: php, file-upload, http-status-code-401

I have the following PHP code to upload files to the server:

```
function saveImage2Server($input_name)
{
    $originalFileName = basename($_FILES[$input_name]["name"]);
    if ($originalFileName==""){
        header("Location: ../");
        die(error);
    }
    $dotIndex = strrpos($originalFileName, ".");
    $extension = substr($originalFileName, $dotIndex);
    $newFileName = uniqid().$extension;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$input_name]["tmp_name"], "../../images/".$newFileName);
    return $newFileName;
}
```

It works fine in my localhost. However, when I moved it to live server, uploaded an image with it and tried to access that image - I got the following error:

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
```

I can access other images in the directory, the ones that were uploaded via FTP, bot not the ones I uploaded with PHP. How can it be fixed?

Comment: What are the permissions on the files? Does the `.htaccess` say anything about sending a 401 when it can't read a file? What web server is it?

Comment: It's an IIS of my hosting company, I don't have access to its permissions...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with IIS - what does FTP say the permissions of the files are? If they're your files you should be able to change the permissions of it right from your FTP client (if the directory permissions allow that.) Also check who owns the file (if that's even applicable in the Windows world.)

Comment: I'm using CuteFTP, it doesn't say anything about permissions (unless I'm looking in a wrong place)...

Comment: If you're on CuteFTP, I think the permissions are in a column called `attr`. See what the directory and the file's `attr` looks like.